# Video Credentials

Tags: video, credentials

I put an Asset Library in SharePoint and I upload some videos. In edit Properties there's a tick in the download videos checkbox, but in the site when the user put in the download link the site request credentials. How this can be avoided?

Comment: Does this occur with many browsers? Does this occur with other users? It might be a simple security setting which blocks this, and can be controlled via e.g. IE's settings.

Comment: It is occur in  all the browsers , mozilla, chrome, Internet Explorer.  This happen to all user. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must be clicking on the DOWNLOAD link which gets populated when we move cursor on video thumbnail
But you can download video by following step.
1. click on that video thumbnail.
2. It will open that folder, will play video and show all properties of it.
3. Below properties you will have DOWNLOAD link just click on it.

Thanks